# mongodb - Use a match condition line only based on a condition

Tags: mongodb

I am checking a condition based on environment variable. My goal is to include an extra matching field based on environment variable. Currently I am doing this which works but there is an extra unnecessary check of an arbitrary value of 999.

`const filterByCountry = process.env.SITE_NAME == "awesomeDomain"?"299":"999";`

and then in the match

```
  $match:{
    ... some fields...
    country: { $not: { $eq: filterByCountry } }, // how to use this line only when filterByCountry=true
    },
```

This works because filterByCountry will have a value of "299"(just example) which is what I need to check. I have used 999 which does not even exists in my database to negate the condition (same as not having the whole line).

To avoid that extra processing of checking for 999, how can I wrap the country condition if I change the assignment to:
`const filterByC = process.env.SITE_NAME == "awesomeDomain"//result will be true or false.`

```
  $match:{
    ... some fields...
    if (filterByCountry) {
    country: { $not: { $eq: filterByCountry } }, // how to use this line only when filterByCountry=true
    }
```

I have added an if condition above just to show what I am looking to achieve but thats not a valid mongodb syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter passed to `$match` is also an object, which can be built dynamically as well, like,

```
const filter = {
  ... some fields ...
}

if (process.env.SITE_NAME == "awesomeDomain") { filter.country = { $ne: 299 }}
```

and then

```
{$match: filter}
```